# While Read Line - Limit Number of Lines

Tags: bash, while-loop

I am trying to limit the number of lines found during a while read line loop. For example:

File: order.csv

```
 123456,ORDER1,NEW
 123456,ORDER-2,NEW
 123456,ORDER-3,SHIPPED
```

I am doing the following.

```
 cat order.csv | while read line;
 do
  order=$(echo $line | cut -d "," -f 1)
  status=$(echo $line | cut -d "," -f 3)
  echo "$order:$status"
 done
```

Which outputs:

```
  123456:NEW
  123456:NEW
  123456:SHIPPED
```

How can I limit the number of lines. In this case there are three. How can I limit them to only 2 so that only the first two are displayed?

Desired output:

```
  123456:NEW
  123456:NEW
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some ways to meet your requirements:

**Method 1**

Use `head` to display first few lines of a file.

```
head -n 2 order.csv | while read line;
do
    order=$(echo $line | cut -d "," -f 1)
    status=$(echo $line | cut -d "," -f 3)
    echo "$order:$status"
done
```

**Method 2**

Use a for loop.

```
for i in {1..2}
do
    read line
    order=$(echo $line | cut -d "," -f 1)
    status=$(echo $line | cut -d "," -f 3)
    echo "$order:$status"
done < order.csv
```

**Method 3**

Use `awk`.

```
awk -F, 'NR <= 2 { print $1":"$3 }' order.csv
```